# Combining shape, linetype and colour from different dataframes into one legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am desperatly trying to combine the shapes, linetypes and colors I have specified for different dataframes into the same legend.

I used the follwing code

```
# Define the labels for the dataframes
drought_t1_beta_labels <- c("Rhizosphere W1", "Rhizosphere W3", "Bulksoil W1", "Bulksoil W3")

# Define the colors for the dataframes
drought_t1_beta_colors <- c("#556B2F","#EE7600", "#556B2F", "#EE7600")

# Define shape of data points
drought_t1_beta_shapes <- c(17, 17, 19, 19)

# Define the linetypes for the dataframes
drought_t1_beta_linetypes <- c("solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed")


p.drought_t1_beta <- ggplot(NULL, mapping = aes(x = Con, y = nM_mean)) +
  geom_point(data = RZW1t120, mapping = aes(shape = "Rhizosphere W1"), color = "#556B2F", fill = "#556B2F") +
  geom_line(data = mm.RZW1t120, mapping = aes(linetype = "Rhizosphere W1"), color = "#556B2F") +
  geom_errorbar(data = RZW1t120, mapping = aes(ymin = nM_mean - nM_sd, ymax = nM_mean + nM_sd), color = "#556B2F") +
  geom_point(data = RZW3t120, mapping = aes(shape = "Rhizosphere W3"), color = "#556B2F", fill = "#556B2F") +
  geom_line(data = mm.RZW3t120, mapping = aes(linetype = "Rhizosphere W3"), color = "#556B2F") +
  geom_errorbar(data = RZW3t120, mapping = aes(ymin = nM_mean - nM_sd, ymax = nM_mean + nM_sd), color = "#556B2F") +
  geom_point(data = BSW1t120, mapping = aes(shape = "Bulksoil W1"), color = "#EE7600", fill = "#EE7600") +
  geom_line(data = mm.BSW1t120, mapping = aes(linetype = "Bulksoil W1"), color = "#EE7600") +
  geom_errorbar(data = BSW1t120, mapping = aes(ymin = nM_mean - nM_sd, ymax = nM_mean + nM_sd), color = "#EE7600") +
  geom_point(data = BSW3t120, mapping = aes(shape = "Bulksoil W3"), color = "#EE7600", fill = "#EE7600") +
  geom_line(data = mm.BSW3t120, mapping = aes(linetype = "Bulksoil W3"), color = "#EE7600") +
  geom_errorbar(data = BSW3t120, mapping = aes(ymin = nM_mean - nM_sd, ymax = nM_mean + nM_sd), color = "#EE7600") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 200)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 50)) +
  xlab(x_exp) +
  ylab(y_exp) +
  theme_classic()+
scale_shape_manual(values = drought_t1_beta_shapes, labels = drought_t1_beta_labels) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = drought_t1_beta_linetypes, labels = drought_t1_beta_labels) +
  scale_color_manual(values = drought_t1_beta_colors, labels = drought_t1_beta_labels) +
  labs(shape = " ", color = NULL, linetype = NULL)

p.drought_t1_beta
```

which gave me this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owNee.png)

This is pretty much how I wanted it except that I want the shape and the line to be combined and not on in the upper half of the legend and the other one below that.

Any good suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Try with `labs(shape = NULL, color = NULL, linetype = NULL)`, i.e. you added a different name for the shape guide. Hence, you get a separate legend.

Comment: Oh man. It worked! Such a stupid mistake!